# "Connection lines" instead of "Connection points" in VISIO

Tags: microsoft-visio

I wonder if this is possible:

Make a line or the whole perimeter of a figure "Connectable" in VISIO. ie, Not connection points but connection lines. (or say, a line full of connection points)

Plus, if needed, lock the intersection point at the current relative position or a relative range, and release from lock when later mind changed.

update: Just found out, if a figure doesn't have any connection points, then it will connect direct to the line instead.
But I want to keep the basic connection points, yet can still to choose whether a new line auto-connect to near connection points or just connect to the line's nearest intersection, and better yet to lock intersection at the relative point. -- Is this possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the **Snap & Glue** -> **Glue to** settings to include:
**Shape geometry**

Comment: It worked. Thanks :)     btw, if someone wondered: hold alt can fine-turning the intersection position.

Comment: I too had such requirement, it worked fine.